# How pass string variable java from one method to another method

Tags: java

I am new on Java android code, please help me how to access String variable from one method to another method, this is from my code, I want to use variable deviceToken, to pass the value to another method that using javascriptinterface

```java
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d("TokenFcm",token);

        String deviceToken = token ;

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
```

Comment: You basically need to store the value in a field, not a local variable. (So declare `deviceToken` outside the `onNewToken` method, and just assign a new value to it in the method.)

Comment: Can you  please give me example how to declare variable deviceToken outside the new onNewToken to store token value from onNewToken method

Comment: I'm afraid at this point, I'd really suggest starting with a good Java tutorial. You really *need* to know about fields - and dozens of other things. Trying to write Android code without a firm grasp of the basics of the programming language you're using is going to be unproductive. Trying to address that one small question at a time is not an efficient way of doing it for either you or the people you're asking for help - I'd strongly advise you to try to learn the basics in a more systematic way.

Answer (score 0):

1. by declaring deviceToken as instance variable, it can be accessed from anotherMethod of same class

````
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

String deviceToken = "";

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d("TokenFcm",token);

         deviceToken = token ;

    }
    
    public void anotherMethod(){
     System.out.println(deviceToken);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    } ```
````

Comment: You might want to rephrase "global variable" to "instance variable". Java doesn't support global variables